# Spring cloud stream with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

Need some help in integrating kafka with spring cloud stream. The application is very simple, with 2 parts(run as separate java processes)

1. A consumer- puts request into RequestTopic and gets response from ResponseTopic
2. A producer- gets the request from the RequestTopic and puts the response back in ResponseTopic.

I have created RequestSenderChannel and ResponseReceiverChannel interfaces for consumer and  RequestReceiverChannel and  ResponseSenderChannel
for the producer application. both of them share the same yaml file. 
As per the documentation spring.cloud.stream.bindings..destination should specify the topic to which the message is sent or received.
But when i run the application, the application creates topics as 'RequestSender', 'RequestReceiver', 'ResponseSender' and 'ResponseReceiver' in the kafka

My assumption was: since destination in the YAML file specifies only two topics 'RequestTopic' and 'ResponseTopic', it should have created those topics.
but it creates Kafka topics for attributes specified at 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings' in the YAML file.
can someone please point out the issue in the configruation/code?

```
public interface RequestReceiverChannel
{
    String requestReceiver ="RequestReceiver";
    @Input(requestReceiver)
    SubscribableChannel pathQueryRequest();
}

public interface RequestSenderChannel
{
    String RequestSender ="RequestSender";
    @Output(RequestSender)
    MessageChannel pathQueryRequestSender();
}

public interface ResponseReceiverChannel
{
    String ResponseReceiver = "ResponseReceiver";
    @Input(ResponseReceiver)
    SubscribableChannel pceResponseServiceReceiver();
}
public interface ResponseSenderChannel
{
    String ResponseSender = "ResponseSender";
    @Output(ResponseSender)
    MessageChannel pceResponseService();
}
'''
```

The YAML configuration file

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      defaultBinder: kafka
      bindings:
        RequestSender:
          binder: kafka
          destination: RequestTopic
          content-type: application/protobuf
          group: consumergroup
        ResponseSender:
          binder: kafka
          destination: ResponseTopic
          content-type: application/protobuf
          group: consumergroup
        RequestReceiver:
          binder: kafka
          destination: RequestTopic
          content-type: application/protobuf
          group: consumergroup
        ResponseReceiver:
          binder: kafka
          destination: ResponseTopic
          content-type: application/protobuf
          group: consumergroup
      kafka:
        bindings:
          RequestTopic:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
          ResponseTopic:
            consumer:
              autoCommitOffset: false
        binder:
          brokers: ${SERVICE_KAFKA_HOST:localhost}
          zkNodes: ${SERVICE_ZOOKEEPER_HOST:127.0.0.1}
          defaultZkPort: ${SERVICE_ZOOKEEPER_PORT:2181}
          defaultBrokerPort: ${SERVICE_KAFKA_PORT:9092}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.<binding-name>.destination=foo` you are expressing desire to map binding specified by `<binding-name>` (e.g., `RequestSender`) to a broker destination named `foo`. If such destination does not exist it will be auto-provisioned.
So there are no issues.

That said, we've just released Horsham.RELEASE (part of cloud Hoxton.RELEASE) and we are moving away from annotation-based model you are currently using in favor of a significantly simpler functional model. You can read more about it in our [release blog](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/25/announcing-the-release-of-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-3-0-0-release) which also provides links to 4 posts where we elaborate and provide more examples on functional programming paradigm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if what you are saying is true(same as the documentation), then it should have created a topic called foo but it seems to be creating a topic of "binding name" which is not what the document says. I expected the configuration to create 2 topics ''RequestTopic" and "ResponseTopic"(the configuration has two destinations only) but it created 4 topics of ''RequestSender", "RequestReceiver", "ResponseSender" and "ResponseReceiver". why is this so? thanks for the latest link, i will check it out.

Comment: Ok, then it looks like it's not picking up your YAML file at all. Can you post a link to your app somewhere on Github so we can take a look?

Comment: thanks for the hint. yes. the yaml file was not picked up properly! cloudstream should have thrown an error then! i debugged it for a day! :)

Comment: Not having any configuration file is a valid condition, since there are sensible defaults in place, possibility to provide configuration via system properties and/or environment variables etc. So, what kind of error do you expect on a valid condition?

Comment: Oh.. if not having a config file is a valid condition then it makes sense! probably it will help if the documentation should make it clear? just a suggestion or probably i didn't read the documentation properly! thanks again for the clarification.